# Mocking Firebase in JUnit

Tags: java, maven, junit, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a Java application that makes use of Firebase and the RealtimeDB.

While writing my unit tests, I ran into a rather strange issue in that the Firebase classes can not be loaded inside JUnit, throwing a NoSuchMethodError:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger.asUnsigned(I)Lcom/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInteger;`

I've managed to track it down to Firebase using a different Guava version than the rest of the project, but even though I've forced the use of Guava 19.0 (through the Maven dependency exclusion mechanism), I'm still getting the same error, apparently when the FirebaseOptions class is being loaded (exact location: `com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.setServiceAccount(FirebaseOptions.java:77)`).

EDIT:
The problem only appears during a test run, at run-time, the Guava library is loaded correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to provide Firebase with the Guava library properly?

Comment: Add your dependency, because this look like old version of Guava

Comment: @Hrabosch I tried that, both by adding the Guava that is in the Firebase POM explicitly, and by letting Maven resolve it transitively (which it has, I can see it reappearing in my local Maven cache after a purge), to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the solution was to add the resolution exclusion to the POM (making the final dependency as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

), then force a purge of the local repository. After re-indexing the project, the test were able to load the appropriate classes without issues.